# spread properties with multiple changes: one-liner ecma immutability

Tags: javascript, redux, immutability, ecmascript-next

I just changed this

```
const newCities = {...newState.cities};
newCities[action.payload.id] = action.payload;
newState.cities = newCities;
```

to a one-liner

```
newState.cities = {...newState.cities, [action.payload.id]: action.payload};
```

But how do I change this

```
const newCities = {...newState.cities};
action.payload.forEach(city=> newCities[city.id] = city);
newState.cities = newCities;
```

to a one-liner? Something ~=

```
newState.cities = {...newState.cities, action.payload.map(city=> [city.id]: city)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final solution:**

```
newState.cities = {...newState.cities, ...action.payload.reduce((o,a)=> ({...o,[a.id]:a}),{})};
```

Previously I forgot to initialize reduce array =)

**Old approaches:**
May be this way?

```
newState.cities = {...newState.cities, ...action.payload.map(city=> ({[city.id]: city}) )};
```

**Updated:**

```
newState.cities = {...newState.cities, ...action.payload.reduce(city=> ({[city.id]:city}) )};
```

**Update (complete ugliness):**

```
newState.cities = {...newState.cities, ...action.payload.map((o)=> ({[o.id]:o}) ).reduce((o,a)=>({...o,...a}))};
```

Comment: error...! problem with nesting! [playground here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=let%20city%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20cities%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20action%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aaction.payload%20%3D%20%5B%7Bid%3A1%7D%2C%7Bid%3A2%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newState%20%3D%20%7B...city%7D%3B%0D%0AnewState.cities%20%3D%20%7B...newState.cities%2C%20...action.payload.map(city%3D%3E%20(%7B%5Bcity.id%5D%3A%20city%7D)%20)%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(newState.cities)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: still not complete :( [pg](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=let%20city%20%3D%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20cities%3A%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20action%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aaction.payload%20%3D%20%5B%7Bid%3A2%7D%2C%7Bid%3A3%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20newState%20%3D%20%7B...city%7D%3B%0D%0AnewState.cities%20%3D%20%7B...newState.cities%2C%20...action.payload.reduce(city%3D%3E%20(%7B%5Bcity.id%5D%3Acity%7D)%20)%7D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(city.cities)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(newState.cities)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: @ZekeDran can you provide babel example with test data input?

Comment: playground links I've used above have that; and can you add a brief explanation for yo code?

Comment: @ZekeDran here is final answer, I guess it should work as you wanted

Comment: :D the trick is to convert the array of objects into an object with keyed ids, and then spread its properties _(rather than building an array and spread its elements which would not have keys)_ to add it to spre(a)d properties of original object...